# Program won't read past the first entry in file

Tags: c++, file, file-io, structure, character-arrays

I need help fixing this C++ program that is not writing the second entry in one file to another file. It only seems to be writing the first entry only to the file and then after that the while loop is terminating, even though the end of the file has not been reached. Here is the program:

```
indata.open("income.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);

while (true)
{
    indata.ignore();
    indata.getline(person[count2].name, NAMESIZE); 
    indata >> person[count2].income;
    indata >> person[count2].rent;
    indata >> person[count2].food;
    indata >> person[count2].utilities;
    indata >> person[count2].miscell;

    if (count2 == 0)
    {
        outdata << setw(20) << "Name"
                << setw(10) << "Income"
                << setw(10) << "Rent" 
                << setw(10) << "Food"
                << setw(15) << "Utilities"
                << setw(15) << "Miscellaneous"
                << setw(10) << "Net Money" << endl << endl;
    }

    outdata << setw(20) << person[count2].name 
            << setw(10) << person[count2].income 
            << setw(10) << person[count2].rent 
            << setw(10) << person[count2].food 
            << setw(15) << person[count2].utilities 
            << setw(15) << person[count2].miscell 
            << setw(10) << person[count2].net << endl;

    count2++;
}

outdata.close();
```

Conditions I have tested in the while loop include, `indata`, `!indata.eof()`, and `indata.good()`.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Try stripping out all the code unrelated to the problem. [I'm serious](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And as a general observation. stop assuming your IO *works*. This code can fail in a plethora of places and yet you march on as if nothing happened. *Check your IO calls*.

Comment: @beta Although I believe all the code was relevant, I have edited it to include the part where I think the problem is occurring .

Comment: @Justin What was at the core of Beta's point was this: if the posted code can be used *by us* to reproduce the problem, then its enough. If it can't then it isn't. If it has *nothing to do with the problem*, and the issue can be reproduced *without it*, then it probably doesn't belong in the post. Applying *all* of that, and you have yourself an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The problem will likely be found in short order, and surprisingly, *you* are the one that will likely find it (while piecing together the MCVE). If you don't, we probably can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem:

I couldn't figure out how to get the while loop to iterate more than once for this particular case, so I used a for loop:

```
indata.open("income.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);

   for (count2 = 0 ; count2 < count + 1 ; count2++)
   {
    indata.ignore();
    indata.getline(person[count2].name, '\n'); 
    indata >> person[count2].income;
    indata >> person[count2].rent;
    indata >> person[count2].food;
    indata >> person[count2].utilities;
    indata >> person[count2].miscell;
    indata >> person[count2].net;

    if (count2 == 0)
    {   
        // write information to output file
        outdata << setw(20) << "Name" << setw(10) << "Income" << setw(10) << "Rent" 
            << setw(10) << "Food" << setw(15) << "Utilities" << setw(15)
                << "Miscellaneous" << setw(10) << "Net Money" << endl << endl;
    }

    outdata << setw(20) << person[count2].name 
                << setw(10) << person[count2].income 
                << setw(10) << person[count2].rent 
                << setw(10) << person[count2].food 
                << setw(15) << person[count2].utilities 
                << setw(15) << person[count2].miscell 
                << setw(10) << person[count2].net << endl;
   }

   outdata.close();
```

For this particular case, use count from a previous instance as a condition for the for loop.